# Three different time response on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, benchmarking

I'm querying my database whit ES 2.3.1 and I've been measuring the times responses, but I got three different times.
First I measured the time of the first query on database. It takes about 9 seconds.
Second time I measured, I closed the ES, cleared the RAM and cache and query again. It takes about 1,2 seconds.
The third time I queried without cleaning caches and it takes 97 ms.
Can anyone explain way it happens?
The last measure I know that its faster because the data already queried is on cache. I think the first time takes more time because the data have to be pulled on cache.
For me, when I clear the cache and RAM, the time of the second measuring had to be equal the first measure, but no. Can someone explain me way?

Comment: How did you clear the cache?

Comment: Watch the caches being cleared or not with `GET /_stats/query_cache,fielddata,request_cache`

Comment: I clear the cache this way: 
$ curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_cache/clear' and while ES was closed I used: echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches too.

Comment: The commandI gave shows the expected behavior?

Comment: How are you clearing the RAM? Is it running on Linux? Lucene has been optimized for the OS so that is important to understand.

Comment: @hubbardr It's running on Ubuntu 14.04.  I clear the cache this way: $ curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_cache/clear'; and while ES was closed I used: echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches too.